# How to run batch SQL file using c#?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I want to run a big set of SQL statements in one go in c#; this SQL also contains numerous local variables. I tried to run that SQL using ADO.Net but I got an exception: "Cannot declare more than 10000 local variables". Can I run these SQL statements in a batch file (using c#) to avoid this exception/limitation? If yes, how? Is there any better approach?

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 and C# 4.0.

Looking forward to assistance.

Answer (score 1):

> "Cannot declare more than 10000 local variables"

I expect that's a SQL Server limitation (albeit not listed in "[Maximum Capacity Specifications for SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx)"), if correct then all methods of running at a single script will have the same problem.

Better to break it up into smaller pieces—this should also make maintenance much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a .bat file that runs sqlcmd and exec your batch sql file.  in c# you can then launch a cmd window as a process, sending the location of the .bat file as an argument.

Comment: Or just launch the .bat as the process.